# Force.com app for the client

Tags: force.com

I am developing a finance cum Inventory managemnt app for my client.

I have a developer account but if my client want to use this app then he will require a salesforce account and also few licenses for his employees(10)

Can somebody suggest me the best options available( 10= 4 [read/write], 6[read only] )

I am afraid for telling my customer to buy any license type if he then not able to use my app.

It is very clear that client dont want to spend on devops people and server management  by developing a custom application. So, I suggested him Paas but Salesforce people are not very clear in their pricing. They should guide by telling clearly what need to be done for a company who want to access the platform with only few custom apps and not any other things.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty terrible question.

You can find out about the different license types from the Salesforce Help pages:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm&type=0

Determining what kind of license you need is then up to you.

Regarding your question about read vs read/write, that is more likely a *Profile* decision than a licensing one.

Finally, don't use a developer edition org for a client deliverable. DE orgs aren't bound by the same SLAs as a proper production org. Tell your client to procure one.

Comment: yes, i can see the license types but then different editions are there like enterprise, developer etc etc.  I am afraid for telling my customer to buy any license type if he then not able to use my app.  He is very clear, he want to save money by cutting devops people and server costs from his company. Salesforce people are not very clear in their pricing. They should guide by telling clearly what need to be done for a company who want to access the platform with only few custom apps and not any other things.

Comment: @vijaynair - How is copying your question as a comment supposed to clarify. If the user did not understand your question copying the question will not help the user to understand it any better